# Retrieving the user data with the value in array in PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php

Hello guys i inserted some arrays in the database using the html check boxes and it worked fine.
 Now i wan't to check for students with the years and study modes in the array. But it's not working i have tried this below:

```
$StudyYears = $rows['study_years'];  
$StudyModes = $rows['study_modes'];
```

"SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE `study_mode` IN ('$StudyModes')";

Comment: How `$StudyModes` looks/contain? Please give example

Comment: $StudyYears = $rows['study_years'];  
 and $StudyModes = $rows['study_modes'];

Comment: That will likely give you `SELECT * FROM students WHERE study_mode IN ('Array')`, which obviously won't work as you expect.

Comment: @ComfortChambeshi LOL ok. . what `$rows['study_years']` contains? If array show that array. .. We must see the value of it.

Comment: in study years there is only one,two,three

Comment: what about modes?

Comment: Distance,Online

Comment: On the other hand if `$StudyModes` is a CSV, or other delimited string, you may end up with `SELECT * FROM students WHERE study_mode IN ('a,b,c')` in which case you will need to explode the string into an array, then implode them with individual quotes. Though I'd suggest using prepared statements / parameterised queries.

Comment: @Jonnix there is solution OP need!

Comment: @Jonnix Yes but how can i go about it?

Comment: Google has tons of example for this

Comment: I think you just need `SELECT study_years,study_modes FROM students `

Comment: The [explode](http://php.net/explode) docs are pretty self explanatory and the docs for [implode](https://www.php.net/implode) have an example in the comments of creating a quoted string from a list. Prepared statements stuff would depend on whether you were using, or are wanting to use the mysqli_* or PDO APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actyally `FIND_IN_SET()` also could work for you:
https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE FIND_IN_SET (study_mode , '".$StudyModes."')
```

If you want to look for both:

```
SELECT * FROM students 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET (study_years , '".$StudyYears ."') 
AND FIND_IN_SET (study_mode , '".$StudyModes."')
```

Comment: I edited. .. you can use `AND` or `OR` to use other columns in `WHERE`

Comment: Just be careful of what you pass in query from user input! I would suggest to use mysqli prepared statements or PDO